# Understanding the logic of this method to find the position of the largest element in the array

Tags: java, arrays, logic

The purpose of this method is to return the position (subscript index) of the largest element in the array (not its value, but its position). If the same maximum value appears more than once in the array, then it should return the position of the first or earliest on. If the array has no elements it should just return -1.

The solution:

```
public static int maxPos(int[] arr) {
  int pos = 0;
    if(arr.length > 0 ) {
      for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] > arr[pos]) {
         pos = i;
    } else {
    pos = - 1;
    }
 }
   return pos;
}
```

I understand setting up a dummy variable "pos" to represent the index position of the maximum value of the array. And having the check point with if(arr.length > 0) then proceed. And the for-loop to sift through the entire array checking one-by-one which index has the greatest number value and after each iteration either re-assigning dummy variable or carrying onward.
The part where I get lost is when using things within the array [ ]'s, it throws me off. I don't think anywhere else in java there is such notation. For example with arrayList wouldn't that just be nameOfAL . get();
So the equivalent of that for an array is using the []'s?
I am a bit confused by arr[i] > arr[pos].
Is this to say when we are at the i'th index in the for-loop, we can then use arr[] and put something within that box, and when we do it outputs the value of that index. So anytime we put something within that array box it's always going to output an index position? is that the purpose of putting things inside the [] box? it will output the value of whatever is put inside it's brackets.
the next part that confuses me is why pos = i?
I understand if the if-statement fails then the else is - 1. but why return pos; after each iteration?

Thank you

Comment: So, your question is that you don't understand the notation for accessing the nth element of an array? See [this Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: I suspect the return is meant to be outside the closing brace of the `for`.

Comment: Have you tried this method? It does not work.

Comment: Whitespace is not the enemy.

Comment: @dramzy part of it. But I am just generally trying to understand the overall code.

Comment: See the tutorial I linked to. It's very simple, `array[0]` means get the element stored at the first position of `array`, for example. You seem to understand the general algorithm, the part that's tripping you up is the array access notation in Java.

Comment: @dramzy in your experience is that mainly what we use array for? to create space, fill that space, then access it? and the way to access it is by using the [] notation and putting something in between those brackets and that will be always an index.

Comment: you are not returning pos after each iteration

Comment: the pos = i; was dumb on my part, I understand it. It's the array part for sure. Arrays confuse me and their notation.

Comment: "Why pos = i?" Initially pos is set to the first index in the array (i.e., 0). The for loop causes i to loop from 0 to the last index in the array, and if the array element at `i` is greater than the element at index `pos` then `pos` is set to the index of the greater element using the statement `pos = i`.  At the end of the loop, `pos` points to the index of the greatest array element. Strictly speaking `i` should go from 1 to the last index, to avoid comparing the element at 0 with itself.

Comment: @efekctive please explain.

Comment: Look at the code. return statement is outside the loop.

Comment: @DavidChoweller I get it now, I think. I don't know if I would have been able to figure this out on my own. So what's happen is that the for loop starts and say we have an array: 5,4,2,8....it would go arr[0] > arr[0], nope they are the same guys. arr[1] > arr[0], is 4 > 5, nope, no re-assigning of i. arr[2] > arr[0], is 2 > 5, nope. arr[3] > arr[0], 8 > 5, yes! now pos = i, is pos = 8. Then if there was more in the array it will keep on checking and either re-assigning or carrying on.

Comment: @jun No, `pos` is not 8.  Pos is set to the index of 8, which (in your example) would be 3.

Comment: @DavidChoweller oh right! it would be the index of the highest value, pos = 3.

Comment: @jun Also, you don't need to return `pos` after every iteration. You return `pos` after you've gone through the entire array from 1 through the last index.

Comment: @DavidChoweller thank you for being patient with me.

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code contains a few bugs, you should start with `pos` at `-1` (instead of resetting it when a given value isn't greater then the current max). Also, I would check for `null`. Then you can start your loop with the second element. Something like,

```
public static int maxPos(int[] arr) {
    int pos = -1; // <-- indicates no elements.
    if (arr != null && arr.length > 0) {
        pos = 0; // <-- there is at least one element.
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[pos]) {
                pos = i; // <-- update the max position
            }
        }
    }
    return pos;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
why would we start at 1 rather than 0 of the array indices? why is -1 best to use? still confused by when to use it and how i works.

Comment: Because `-1` is to be returned when the array doesn't have any elements. Once you determine that it does, you can then *start* with the assumption that the first element is the greatest (and then check if the second and on is actually greater).

Answer (score 0):

First, so what you're putting in the square braces are variables named `i` and `pos` that hold the values of the numerical positions you're accessing in the array. It's like the get method of the arrayList class like that.

It's not returning `pos` until it finishes the for loop. In general it's returning `pos` because that's the index of the largest number, which is the point of the program. I think you're just missing a bracket somewhere, you have 5 `{`'s and 4 `}`'s.